# Inherited abstract type in case class constructor

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I am translating some parametrized F-Bounded types to abstract type classes. The original classes were:

```
sealed trait A[AA <: A[AA]] {
  self =>
  val data: String
}
case class AInst(data: String) extends A[AInst]

sealed trait B[BB <: B[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: BB =>
  val content: AA
}
case class BInst[AA <: A[AA]](content: AA) extends B[BInst[AA], AA]
```

I would like to have two identical case classes, but the traits should loose all their parameters. Here is my attempt:

```
sealed trait A2 {
  self =>
  type AA <: A2 {type AA = self.AA}
  val data: String
}

case class A2Inst(data: String) extends A2

sealed trait B2 {
  self =>
  type BB <: A2 {type BB = self.BB}
  type AA <: A2 {type AA = self.AA}
  val content: AA
  }

case class B2Inst[AHere <: A2 {type AA = AHere}](content: AHere) extends B2 {
  self =>
  type AA = AHere
}

val a2 = A2Inst("A2")
val b2 = B2Inst(a2)
```

Unfortunately `B2Inst` does not compile. What is the correct definition for the case class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the type refinement in the definition of `A2Inst`.

```
case class A2Inst(data: String) extends A2 { type AA = A2Inst }
```

All together:

```
sealed trait A2 {
  self =>
  type AA <: A2 {type AA = self.AA}
  val data: String
}
case class A2Inst(data: String) extends A2 { type AA = A2Inst }

sealed trait B2 {
  self =>
  type BB <: A2 {type BB = self.BB}
  type AA <: A2 {type AA = self.AA}
  val content: AA
}

case class B2Inst[AHere <: A2 {type AA = AHere}](content: AHere) extends B2 {
  self =>
  type AA = AHere
}

val a2 = A2Inst("A2")
val b2 = B2Inst(a2)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait A2
defined class A2Inst
defined trait B2
defined class B2Inst
a2: A2Inst = A2Inst(A2)
b2: B2Inst[A2Inst] = B2Inst(A2Inst(A2))
```

Comment: oh dear, bad me! is there any other way to write the type parameter for `B2Inst`, or is `AHere <: A2 {type AA = AHere}` the only way?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Since it needs to infer the type from the parameter that's passed, you need the type refinement. I suppose you could define a type alias (outside) like: `type CC[C] = A2 { type AA = C }` and then use it like this: `case class B2Inst[AHere <: CC[AHere]](content: AHere)`. I'm not sure I would call that better, especially since the question is about avoiding the F-bounded syntax.